# Trickery, is it really that awesome?

Tags: rogue, shadow-of-the-demon-lord

In [Shadow of the Demon Lord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_of_the_Demon_Lord), a level 1 Rogue gains the talent "trickery":

> **Trickery** Once per round, you can make an attack roll or challenge roll with 1 boon. If you attack with 1 boon from this talent, your attack deals 1d6 extra damage.

The way I read this is that it applies to pretty much anything. You want to sneak up on the mansion? Have a boon. You want to sweet-talk the smith into making a pair of those gauntlets? Have a boon. Library research? Making an attack? Resisting a hex? Boon, boon, boon!

It's only once per round, but still, it will very often come down to rogues getting d20 + 3.5 where others only get d20. Also, you do d6 extra damage if you hit with your trickery attack.

So my question is: Am I really reading this correctly?

(If yes, I'm not grieving that there has finally been published an RPG system where the rogue is a powerful class, mind you. Just emotionally overwhelmed, I guess.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Yes, it is that awesome

Trickery is the rogue's thing. Rogues are sneaky bastards, they're adaptable, and they're cunning. The **trickery** talent embodies these things about them.

Each novice path has a "thing" they're good at. A magician will always have more spells (**cantrip** talent). A priest will always have more healing (**shared recovery** talent). A warrior will always be better with weapons (**weapon training** talent). And a rogue will always be more adaptable to the situation at hand.

Comment: This type of bonus comes up a lot in sotdl.  Lots of classes get boons for a wide variety of things.